# Epoch time shows different date in different time zones?

Tags: sql, timezone, epoch

I have an epoch time(seconds) . It shows me different times in `JAVA`, when i do

`new Date(time*1000)`

and in SQL when i do

`SELECT cast((DATE '1970-01-01' + time/24/60/60) as timestamp) from dual`.

The problem mainly is, i need data of a particular interval between 2 AM and 4 AM. So when i pass the seconds value to the SQL query. it interprets it as between 9AM and 11 AM. I understand that this is because of the time zone difference.

How can i overcome this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a timestamp instead:

```
SELECT cast((TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00.00' + time/24/60/60) as timestamp)
  FROM dual
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/1465

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for dealing with any time zone related issues is to always handle times internally as UTC and store them in the data store as UTC.  Only convert them to a local time only for display to the user.